# how to prevent image to load in all pages with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want images to appear in different spots of my window/screen so I have used this function:

```
function im2(a,b,c,d){
 var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", a); 
  x.setAttribute("style",b)
  x.setAttribute("width", c);
  x.setAttribute("height",d );
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

So I call the images as follow when needed

```
im2("js/image2.jpg","position: fixed; top:210px ; left:165px","280","35")
```

etc...

It works fine on web (without jqm), in the mobile app as well BUT ...

I am using jQuery mobile (1.4.5) and the images are loaded in the 3 pages I have (I just need the middle page(page2)). Why?
I am not sure to differentiate if it is a swipe issue or a loading disfunction.

My pages code is

```
 <div data-role="page" id="article3"><!--page3-->
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
      <h1>data table</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1><-- Back </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>3/3</p>
 ---content---

</div> </div>
```

My swipe code is :

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function(event){    
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {    
        var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
        // swipe using id of next page if exists
        if (nextpage.length > 0) { 
            $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: false}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;         
});

$(document).on('swiperight', '.ui-page', function(event){     
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {      
        var prevpage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
        if (prevpage.length > 0) {
            $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}, true, true);
        }
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;            
});
```

I tried this, didn't work:

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); });
```

or this, the same, images still appear on all the pages.

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', '.selector', function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

So may be I didn't put these code lines in the right place, or may be there is nothing to do with the swipe.
I was not able to find any solution so I am asking for help here.
Thank you

Comment: @Stewartside ... I cannot send you a msg so it is my only way for me to let you know that I got inspired by both of you;, but still I cannot resolve my issue... is it possible to tell me if I am in the good path?

Comment: or @UlrichBangert ... I cannot send you a msg so it is my only way for me to let you know that I got inspired by both of you;, but still I cannot resolve my issue... is it possible to tell me if I am in the good path?

Comment: @deblocker thank you for your answer but as you can see , when I call the function im2 , I mention position fixed; actually I tried data- position fixed  in the jqm pages code ...but nothing, images are loaded in all my 3 pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicate it. If you want to put the dynamically created image to specific element you can change this line:
`document.body.appendChild(x);` to this:  `document.querySelector('#article2').appendChild(x);`

But this will ruin the creator so you can pass 5th argument to decide where you want to place your dynamic created image:

```
function im2(a,b,c,d,e){
 var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", a); 
  x.setAttribute("style",b)
  x.setAttribute("width", c);
  x.setAttribute("height",d );
  // this append the image on the body element
  //document.body.appendChild(x);
  //this however will append it on specify id:
  document.querySelector('#'+e).appendChild(x);
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
im2("js/image2.jpg","position: fixed; top:210px ; left:165px","280","35",'article2');
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is correct I also tried with getelementbyId (#article2) instead of body and it works fine.
thank you for your help.